# Rooting the Micromax Canvas A1 Android One Phone (Micromax Canvas A1 AQ4501)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting

Can anyone share experiences rooting the Android One device Micromax Canvas A1  (Micromax Canvas A1 AQ4501)?

I am looking for a trustworthy way, as far as possible.
Please don't say rooting is inherently risky - I know that. I am still looking for *relatively* safe technique(s) and using third party software, if that's required, that is known to be generally reliable.

If any one has rooted this device, were you able to upgrade to the latest Android version after rooting? (It runs Kitkat 4.4.4 by default)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you haven't rooted your Micromax A1 till now. I have Xolo Q1010i and i've rooted it using Kingroot. I am not sure it will works the same for you but anyways you can always give a try.

I have gathered some information from droidviews for your solution to root Micromax A1.

### **Requirements and Precursors**

- Download Minimal FastBoot tool from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/6b3aw3dq8omefyw/mfastboot-v2.zip) and extract the contents to a folder of your choosing. 
  This will help you in setting up fastboot quickly and counter the need for installing the full Android SDK.
- You’ll have to have ADB drivers setup on your PC. Refer to [this guide](http://www.droidviews.com/setup-adb-and-fastboot-on-windows-within-seconds/) if you don’t have them already setup.
- Once ADB and FastBoot are setup, you’ll have to install your device specific drivers by connecting it to the PC via a USB cable. The drivers specific to your device will be automatically installed to your PC if you have a working Internet connection. If a problem arises in driver installation, just download [these drivers](https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top) and manually install them by pointing your PC’s Device Manager to them.
- Enable USB debugging on your device in the Developer Options menu.
- Download [SuperSU installable](https://download.chainfire.eu/452/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.02.zip).

**NOTE:** **Remember to backup your personal data and charge-up your Canvas A1.**

### **Unlock Bootloader**

- Connect your device to your Computer after enabling USB debugging from the above-mentioned steps. If the first time you connect your device to the PC and a pop-up like this appears on your Canvas, click on ‘Always allow’ and then OK.

---

[image: USB Debugging dialog box]

---

- Now, open the FastBoot folder and right-click on an empty space while holding down the SHIFT key, and then click ‘Open Command Window here’.
- Next, in the Command prompt, type  the following code:

  ```
           adb reboot bootloader
  ```
- Your device will now reboot into fastboot mode.
- The bootloader can now be unlocked by entering the following simple command

  ```
          fastboot oem unlock

          fastboot format userdata
  ```
- That’s it! your bootloader is now unlocked!

### **Install ClockWorkMod/TWRP/Philz Touch Recovery**

- First and foremost, download the recovery you want to install from the below link:

[ClockWorkMod v6.0.5.1](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23681161096069936)

- Now extract recovery image from the zip file to the fastboot folder.
- Open cmd command prompt and enter the following command:

  ```
          fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

          fastboot reboot
  ```
- Done! Your phone now has a working recovery.

### **Root Micromax Canvas A1**

- Start by copying the SuperSU installable update.zip to your device.
- Now, to boot into recovery, just open the command prompt and type:

  ```
           adb reboot bootloader
  ```
- And now comes the time for the good old method of flashing SuperSU via recovery by browsing to its zip file. For this, go to ‘choose zip -> /external_sd’ and go ahead with the install.
- On reboot, you may or may not get a warning similar to ‘su may have been removed’, ignore that and click ‘No’.
- Once this is done, you’ll be sporting a rooted device!